# What does type ByKey []mr.KeyValue{} mean?

Tags: go

I am completely new in Go and have no idea when different language features bump up together,

```
 type ByKey []mr.KeyValue{}
```

could any one please explain what this means?

Comment: `type ByKey` defines a new type named `ByKey` - and this type is a slice (`[]`) of `mr.KeyValue` where `mr` is an imported package that has an exported type `KeyValue`.

Comment: sorry for left out {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [golang.org/ref/spec#Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)

> A type determines a set of values together with operations and methods
> specific to those values. A type may be denoted by a type name, if it
> has one, or specified using a type literal, which composes a type from
> existing types.

And in [Type_declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations)

> Type definitions
>
> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with
> the same underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds
> an identifier to it.

`type ByKey []mr.KeyValue` is a type definition. It creates a new type called `ByKey` with underlying type of `[]mr.KeyValue`. `KeyValue` is again defined exported type in a different package imported  as `mr` to current file which included `type ByKey []mr.KeyValue`.

Comment: given the name this is probably a type used to attach sorting semantics to a slice; it should have methods named `Len`, `Less`, and `Swap`, and it's used as `sort.Sort(ByKey(some_slice))`